# Re-render HTML elements positioning on window resize inside Javascript slide animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have the following website wixwebsite.seobrasov.com where I have a Jquery script that animates the pages to slide in and slide out. I have a formula to calculate the center positioning depending on the browser window which is this:

```
left: Math.max(0,(($(window).width() - 980)/2))
```

where 980 is my div's width.

However, on window resize, the divs remain in the old position and only realign on refresh.

What I am trying to do is to re-center the active page on window resize. I have already tried to include the function in document ready with window resize but that doesn't work. 
Here is my script code:

```
function animate() {
   var currentPageI = -1;
   var pages = [
    $('div.dhome'),
    $('div.dabout'),
    $('div.dcontact'),
    $('div.dportraits'),
    $('div.dpregnancy'),
    $('div.dbabies-newborn'),
    $('div.dbabies-3-6'),
    $('div.dbabies-6-24'),
    $('div.dkids'),
    $('div.dfamily'),
    $('div.dall-about-me'),
    $('div.dcouples'),
    $('div.dpets'),
    $('div.dthe-experience'),
    $('div.dfinishing-touches'),
    $('div.dthank-you'),
    ];

    var viewsWidth = 1300; 
    var showPage = function(index){

    if(index === currentPageI){return;}

    var currentPage = pages[currentPageI];
    if(currentPage){
        currentPage.stop().animate({left: -viewsWidth})
    }

    var nextPage = pages[index];

    nextPage
        .stop()
        .css({left: viewsWidth + Math.max(0,(($(window).width() - 980)/2))})
        .animate({left: Math.max(0,(($(window).width() - 980)/2))})
    currentPageI = index;
  }

  // show default page
  showPage(0);

  $('a.dhome').click(showPage.bind(null, 0));
  $('a.dabout').click(showPage.bind(null, 1));
  $('a.dcontact').click(showPage.bind(null, 2));
  $('a.dportraits').click(showPage.bind(null, 3));
  $('a.dpregnancy').click(showPage.bind(null, 4));
  $('a.dbabies-newborn').click(showPage.bind(null, 5));
  $('a.dbabies-3-6').click(showPage.bind(null, 6));
  $('a.dbabies-6-24').click(showPage.bind(null, 7));
  $('a.dkids').click(showPage.bind(null, 8));
  $('a.dfamily').click(showPage.bind(null, 9));
  $('a.dall-about-me').click(showPage.bind(null, 10));
  $('a.dcouples').click(showPage.bind(null, 11));
  $('a.dpets').click(showPage.bind(null, 12));
  $('a.dthe-experience').click(showPage.bind(null, 13));
  $('a.dfinishing-touches').click(showPage.bind(null, 14));
  $('.submit').click(showPage.bind(null, 15));
  $('a.dthank-you').click(showPage.bind(null, 16));

  $('.content-wrap').mouseover(function(){
    $('.slider').stop().animate({
        right: 0
    }, 50000);                        
  }).mouseout(function(){
    $('.slider').stop().animate({
        right: '-1300px'    
    }, 50000);     
  });
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    animate();
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    animate();
});
```

I even tried to add a css left style line inside the function with `window.resize` and on the `currentPage` but it's still not working. It's as if the `window.resize` doesn't do anything.

Thank you!

Comment: you havnot called the animate function on window resize event...$(window).resize(function(){})

Comment: I have included it, only that forgot to include it here as well. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to get it fixed. 
After the `a.showPage` I included a center function: 
          `$(window).resize(function(){center()});`

that runs as follows and now it adjusts on browser resize:

```
    var center = function(index){
    if(index === currentPageI){return;}
    var currPage = pages[currentPageI];
    if(currPage){
    currPage
        .stop()
        .css({left: viewsWidth + Math.max(0,(($(window).width() -    980)/2))})
        .animate({left: Math.max(0,(($(window).width() - 980)/2))})
    }
    var nextPage2 = pages[index];
    nextPage2
        .stop()
        .css({left: viewsWidth + Math.max(0,(($(window).width() - 980)/2))})
        .animate({left: Math.max(0,(($(window).width() - 980)/2))})
    currentPageI = index;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect a browser resize event with jQuery's [`.resize()`](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) function.

So you would need to do the math every time the event is called.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   redrawDiv();
});

function redrawDiv() {
  // do your math here
}
```

**Another solution:**

change the css of your content-wrap div's width to `980px`, you already have `margin:0 auto`;

and in the script you only need to set the `current page` to `left:0` instead of your math stuff.

Comment: I would love to do that only that I didn't write this snippet, I just edited it as I'm a Jquery/Javascript newbie. I tried to do that just that I don't know for which one of the variables to include the .css left style line. Also, shouldn't the variables be reinitialized? Thanks

Comment: I made a quick example for you. http://jsbin.com/zoluraxo/1/edit - As you can see, all you need to do is set your container to a fixed width and margin: 0 auto and send the page-divs to the left and top 0 position

Comment: I cannot give my container a fixed width because I have to have the pages to slide in and out from 100% of the browser window, not just the container. So it has to recalculate the left distance on window resize and I tried to implement it only that I don't know to which of the variables to put it. I can go $(window).resize(function(){.css({left: viewsWidth + Math.max(0,(($(window).width() - 980)/2))})}) but don't see how to do it next if I do it outside the animate function as a separate function

Comment: I updated my example so the it's possible to see the animation through the whole browser width (you may play around with the initial left value). You can access the variables you used if you set them outside of any function. E.g. var test; function(){test = 1};

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort but I am not changing my script, the markup or the css. This script has been adapted to cover some situations and changing it is not an option.

Comment: I have found the solution. You can see it in my question body.